# Create facebook app authorization dialog with jQuery dialog

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, facebook, jquery-ui-dialog

I have an MVC App, i want users to be able to authorize my webapp with their facebook account.

I have a button, when clicked should open a jQuery dialog box with the facebook login/app authorization page in it.

I've tried loading the facebook auth page directly into the dialog with no result. The URL is called and the dialog remains blank. So then i created an iframe in the dialog, now it seems facebook recognizes it's being loaded in an iframe and shows a link to facebook as opposed to the actual authorization page.

My link is correct, if i redirect to it everything works as expected. I don't want to force the user to redirect. I want them stay on the page and go through the authorization process in a dialog.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use the javascript SDK FB.login?.  It uses a popup so the user never leaves your site.

More info and how to: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/525/

Comment: Agreed. I will add that People are very familiar with this method, and are more likely to trust something that comes directly from Facebook than something custom. You will have better adoption rates.

Comment: Well inside the dialog will be the facebook page. I don't want to refresh the parent page. But i am investigating a way to use the js facebook widget without refreshing or redirecintg.. thanks!

Comment: Do you know how i can add a callback or redirect URL to the login button?

Comment: FB.login incudes the ability to use a callback including the response.  example: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/

Comment: Hmm ok cool. i guess i just add this function to the page where i've added the fb login button?